# Read an inconsistent file

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

Which file readers in C can handle reading an inconsistent file? Sometimes the file is "word number" and other times it is just "word". Like this.

```
bob 456
echo
cat 
dog 1101
peacock 300
```

This is what I tried with fscanf. I am surprised it worked. I didn't think fscanf liked inconsistent files. Is there something I need to be worried about? I know fscanf has really bad side effects if you are not careful.

```
while (fscanf(pFile, "%s %d",  nam, &val) !=EOF)
{
    //my work
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to *carefully read the documentation* for [`fscanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html):

> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure. If the input ends before the first matching failure or conversion, EOF shall be returned. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set, EOF shall be returned, and errno shall be set to indicate the error.

I would do something like this:

```
while (TRUE) {
    int matched = fscanf(pFile, "%s %d", nam, &val);

    if (matched == 2) {
        // nam and val are valid
    } else if (matched == 1) {
        // only nam was assigned
    } else {   // Includes EOF case
        // Nothing was assigned
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what happened with the way I have my code? Why didn't I have any issues? Would it be better to use fgetc, fgets, or another file reader? How do you deal with spaces if you don't use EOF?

Comment: @cokedude I misled you a bit about EOF. See my edit.

Comment: @cokedude I can't - you haven't shown all of your code. How are you using `val` in the body of the `while` loop? Most likely, it still has the value from the last time `fscanf` was called, because as I said, `fscanf` never assigned to it.